# Selenium Marionette new connections will no longer be accepted

Tags: java, selenium, marionette

When i'm starting my java program i'm getting this error message:

```
1494797744010   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:5968
1494797744672   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1494797744951   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm J::a FvialSecUrtiiplts _egrertoDri:r  r:e:s oluirncee 70://gre/modul"e s /dAadtdao:n Mnaon]a gSetra.cjks mt,r alcien:e  F165i7l:e UNtSi_lEsR_RgOeRt_DNiOrT(_)I@NrIeTsIoAuLrIcZeE:D/:/ gAre/moddduolneMsa/nFaigleerU tiisl sn.ojts mi:n7i0t i<a lFiizleedU
tils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:671 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:834 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3129 < observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
1494797746182   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50911
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2570: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
maj 14, 2017 11:35:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

While program is running it appears some new errors:

```
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm, line 70: NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/WindowsJumpLists.jsm, line 403: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIJumpListShortcut.app]
JavaScript error: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.pl.LabDolPUOAM.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNgJpGnsPOpCNGmcIvZ9rnqApDcrQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0, line 52: TypeError: a is null
JavaScript error: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.pl.LabDolPUOAM.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCNgJpGnsPOpCNGmcIvZ9rnqApDcrQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0, line 52: TypeError: a is null
```

At the end im getting this information and the program stops working:

```
1494798016809   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
```

What could be the reason for that error and how to fix it? 
I'm using Firefox 53.0.2 and geckodriver 0.16.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. The first set of error what you are seeing as `1494797744951    addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)` is because you havn't configured the geckodriver to suppress/ignore those errors on console. But they are harmless and if not ignored/suppressed you should be fine living with them.
2. The second set of error you see `JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm` are JavaScript errors which again reflects that you haven't configured the geckodriver properly either to ignore or suppress the JavaScript errors from appearing on the console. Again they are harmless and if not ignored/suppressed you should be fine living with them.
3. The last set of error you see `New connections will no longer be accepted` is something serious `Marionette` complaining about which essentially means you are trying a test step which can't be achieved by the geckodriver. Hence you may need to change your code for the geckodriver to procedd with the task.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Great explanation Dev. It clears all doubts. Explanation force me to upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: @RNS Glad to be able to help you :)